# Re-wire spring bean in @Before method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I want to unit test an `@Controller`-annotated class, using JUnit.

Is it possible for Spring to reset ("re-wire") the controller to its default injected state ? 
There would be no problem building a all new controller object.

A workaround I found is to set the constructor's visibility to protected and execute `ControllerObj controllerObj = new ControllerObj()` at the beginning of `@Before`-annotated class but I obviously do not want to increase contructor's visibility just for testing purpose.

Comment: You may want to check `@DirtiesContext` annotation: https://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@mate00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1534211/mate00) the solution was to use the `@DirtiesContext` annotation.