# Unit test a spring component with private constructor without injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a `@Component`-annotated class, injected using a **private** constructor, and `@Autowired`-annotated setters for nested injection.

In order to unit test it, [a workaround I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390044/re-wire-spring-bean-in-before-method) is to use `@SpringBootTest` and `@DirtiesContext` annotations in order to create Spring context with injected component to test and "re-wire" it after each test.

However, I want to unit test this component without its context (in order to avoid having to build all context before every test).

I can without any problem mock every nested injection (as I want to test the controller only here).

Hence my question : how can I "get" this component's instance ? How can I reset it before each test ? How should I then get my mocked nested injections (that I will - I guess - "inject" via my setters) ?

Comment: @Kayaman My bad, I meant to write `@Component`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a private constructor. There is no benefit from having a private constructor and then using reflection to still only call it from the outside. You should only use a private constructor if the class has only static member to make it clearer that the class is not meant to be instantiated or if you are using a static factory method in the same class to create instances.